# mergesort of names passing arguments in C

Tags: c

How do I pass an argument of string arrays e.g *p[50]?

```
void sortnames(char array[],int low,int high){


    int mid;

    if(low<high){
         mid=(low+high)/2;
         sortnames(array,low,mid);
         sortnames(array,mid+1,high);
         mergeSort(array,low,mid,high);
    }
    }
```

the code

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
void sortnames(char **names, int low, int high, int num_names, int *sizes)
```

Here you pass the array of names on the first parameter. The size of the first coordinate has to be `num_names`, so you don't get into segmentation fault problems. Then you can pass on the last parameter an array with the length of each string. This last parameter must also be of size `num_names`, and then `sizes[i]` would inficate the length of string `names[i]`.

EDIT: A segmentation fault is an error that you'll get whenever you're accessing memory that you are not allowed to be touching in C. That usually arrives when you are accessing array elements out of bounds. In order to avoid this, you have to make sure to allocate enough space for your arrays using an appropriate call to `malloc`. So, for example, in order to call your `sortnames` function, you should declare before an array of strings more or less like this (I say more or less because I don't know the context in which you're executing):

```
int num_names // This is the number of names you want to read

// Populate the variable num_names
// ...

char **to_sort = malloc(num_names * sizeof(char *));
int i;
for(i = 0; i < num_names; ++ i)
{
    to_sort[i] = malloc(max_name_size); // Here max_name_size is a static value
                                        // with the size of the longest string 
                                        // you are willing to accept. This is to 
                                        // avoid you some troublesome reallocation
}

// Populate the array with your strings using expressions like 
// to_sort[i] = string_value;
//...

int *sizes = malloc(num_names * sizeof(int));
for(i = 0; i < num_names; ++ i)
{
    sizes[i] = strlen(to_sort[i]);
}
sortnames(to_sort, 0, num_names, sizes);
```

And remember to null-terminate your strings to avoid segmentation faults on the call to `strlen`.

Comment: Please I am already running into segmentation fault with ubuntu 12.10 each time I compile the program it usuall give an error message at the end saying..segmentation fault(core dump). Don't really understand the meaning. Pls share more light on ur explanation it will do me much good and the use of **arr[] and *arr[] with each differences. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Adegbite Philips Mayokun posted an edit with some suggestions, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Method to define

```
char *arr_ofptr[];
```

Example to fill its elements.Here filling first element

```
arr_ofptr[0] = "John Smith";
```

method to pass this array as argument

```
func(arr_ofptr,..
```

Method to pass perticular element of this array

```
func(arr_ofptr[nth], ..
```

Answer (score -1):

you can do this:

```
void sortnames(char *array,int low,int high)
{

 int mid;
 if(low<high)
 {
     mid=(low+high)/2;
     sortnames(array,low,mid);
     sortnames(array,mid+1,high);
     mergeSort(array,low,mid,high);
 }
```

}

with **char *array** you  pass the address of the fist element of the array..

i hope this help..